# Changing ssh keys on a Ubuntu Azure VM from the Dashboard

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine

I have an Ubuntu VM running on azure. I need to ssh connect to it but I have lost my private key since my `home` partition has gone. So, I reinstalled the OS on my local machine and regenerated a new pair pf private/public keys -- which I am already using for github, bitbucket, ecc. Is there any way to set my new public key on the Ubuntu VM from the Azure Portal?

Comment: @jww thanks for pointing out. Since I already found the answer, shall I still post the question there and then the answer as well? Thanks! -- still, it looks like there are already a lot of similar questions here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Actually, there is.

- first you *must* start your VM
- open the window for the VM from the Azure Portal
- scroll down to `reset password`
- select `reset SSH public key` for the `Mode`
- select the proper `user`
- paste the new public key in the `SSH public key` field
- press the `UPDATE` button on top.

[image]

Just tested and worked fine for me.

Comment: I had a Windows VM. So I haven't tested this one. Anyways I upvoted this one. Can you add a screenshot for reference. I will also submit request to update the Azure docs.

Comment: +1, great answer, but this won't change the SSH Key, it will only add the new SSH Key to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file, so both the old and the new key will be valid

Comment: What if the "reset ssh public key" option just isn't there?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether your VM is deployed using the **Classic** or **Resource Manager** deployment model.

Here is a snippet from [How to reset a Linux VM password or SSH key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/classic/reset-access#sshkeyresetcli)

> You can also use the Azure portal to reset the password or **SSH key**
>   of a Linux VM deployed in the classic deployment model. You can't
>   currently use the portal do to this for a Linux VM deployed in the
>   Resource Manager deployment model.

If you are using Resource Manager, then you can do this only via **CLI** or **PS**. Refer this link: [Reset the SSH key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/classic/reset-access#sshkeyresetcli)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to ask: isn't the link you posted referring to CLI 1.0?

Comment: Yes it is referring to CL 1.0

Answer (score 0):

#### how to reset ssh key for default in an azure virtual machine

> Reset SSH settings for default on a virtual machine azure.

`az vm user reset-ssh -n [MyVm] -g [MyResourceGroup]`

[image]

[learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cli/azure/vm/user](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cli/azure/vm/user?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-user-reset-ssh)